# CMake execute_process empty OUTPUT_VARIABLE

Tags: cmake, cygwin, msys2, docker-toolbox

I have a docker container with linux image that executes CMake script. While executing external program using `execute_process` we noticed a problem with missing output in `OUTPUT_VARIABLE`, the problem can be narrowed to following:

```
execute_process(COMMAND /bin/echo TestMessage
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE o
                ERROR_VARIABLE e)
```

This works perfectly fine with **docker-ce** on linux and **Docker Desktop** on windows.
One of the users (using **docker-toolbox**) reported that `${o}` and `${e}` are empty.
There's also a chance that the `docker run` was executed from Cygwin or git-bash (msys2).

Same command executed from command line:

```
bash> /bin/echo TestMessage
```

produces a proper output (`TestMessage`), but CMake doesn't (empty variables).
What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you showing the entire CMake script? To access the variables `o` and `e`, the CMake syntax is `${o}` and `${e}`, respectively. What exactly is the "proper output"? Is it just `TestMessage`, or something more? How are you running this command from the command line? Do you mean `/bin/echo`, or the CMake script itself? Please clarify these details in your **question post** because it is hard to understand the problem at the moment.

Comment: @squareskittles: updated